# How to set backgroud color of solid of border like main page

Tags: android, layout, border, shapes, android-styles

In my page contain a lot of `layout`s and I want to draw a corner to each `layout` so I try:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
     <corners android:radius="5px"/>
     <stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#ababab"/>
     <padding android:left="0dp" 
          android:top="0dp" 
          android:right="0dp" 
          android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

So color of `shape` is white but all I want is only a `border` and use `background` like the default.

How to set it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work. Set color to transparent:

```
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove solid from your shape as follows....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners android:radius="5px"/>
 <stroke  android:width="5dip" android:color="#ababab"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" 
android:top="0dp" 
android:right="0dp" 
android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Comment: what you want to do actually...i think you want to set boarder background of the layout .

Comment: thanks I can do it like I want now (the answer of what I want , is on the previous answer)